# "Invalid Default Value" mssql to MySql migration tool

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-design

hi i got **"Invalid Default Value for "BarcodeAppID"** " when convervting a MsSQL database to MySQL, im new to both so im wondering what MySQL Isn't Supporting syntax wise ? 
Thanks

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `InfoCentre_dbo`.`BrowserBarcodes`;
CREATE TABLE `InfoCentre_dbo`.`BrowserBarcodes` (
  `BarcodeAppID` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT null,
  `BrowserAppID` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT null,
  `BarcodeReaderPort` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `SilverLightServerListeningPort` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BarcodeAppID`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
 DEFAULT 0
```

instead of DEFAULT null.

Comment: Does MySQL Not Support null as a default ?

Comment: it does, but when you choose to let it be NOT NULL, it should never have null as value...

Answer (score 2):

Well, you try to create a field that can't be NULL and you try to set it as NULL :/ !
You have to change your default value or authorized the field to be NULL.